# Hash function and remainder operator

Tags: function, hash, hashtable, operator-keyword

I had a simple question stuck in my mind which has been confusing me for a while. My professor simply said the hash function is key % arraysize. Does this have to be this way for every hash table or is it something that we decide? Do we actually write the hash function for every hash table we create? Can it be something different for example lets say, simply, hash function  = key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the domain of a hash function is much larger than its range.  For example, a hash might accept "all unicode strings less then 2^64 characters long" and output "a 16-bit number".

Yes, for a few applications, using the identity function as a hash function makes sense, although the hash-table starts to look very much like an ordinary array.

For hash-tables generally, modulo (`%`) is a good choice: it's computationally easy and spreads out well enough in the usual cases.  It is not, however, cryptographically strong, and a lot of applications require that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array to store the results which is a fixed size and referenced by the index (in the case of your question, index = key % array_size which is guaranteed to produce a number between 0 and array_size-1). If the index is ever greater than the array size, you have problems. If it's always less then you have wasted space and so the final stage of any hash tends to be the modulo of the size of the array it has to fit in.

Of course, this does not always lead to an even spread and so you may modify the key *before* taking its modulo as the index.